# SELECT no funciona

Tags: php

Buenas tardes, estoy intentado coger los valores de un campo en una tabla con la clausula where de un $_POST que me traigo de otra página. La variable en cuestión es id_stud que me la traigo por POST perfectamente... de hecho cuando la guardo en la base de datos aparece como guardada, pero el select no tengo manera de que funcione:

```
<?php

// Connexion à la base de données
include('bdd.php');
//echo $_POST['title'];
    $id_stud = $_POST['id_stud'];


if (isset($_POST['title']) && isset($_POST['start']) && isset($_POST['end']) && isset($_POST['color'])){

    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $start = $_POST['start'];
    $end = $_POST['end'];
    $color = $_POST['color'];
    $id_teach = $_POST['id_teach'];
    $id_stud = $_POST['id_stud'];
    $query = mysql_query("select * from student where student_id = '$id_stud'");
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
        $name = $row['firstname'];
        $lastn = $row['lastname'];                    
    $nombre = $name." ".$lastn;
    $sql = "INSERT INTO events(title, id_teach, is_stud, start, end, color) values ('$nombre', '$id_teach', '$id_stud', '$start', '$end', '$color')";
    //$req = $bdd->prepare($sql);
    //$req->execute();

    echo $sql;

    $query = $bdd->prepare( $sql );
    if ($query == false) {
     print_r($bdd->errorInfo());
     die ('Erreur prepare');
    }
    $sth = $query->execute();
    if ($sth == false) {
     print_r($query->errorInfo());
     die ('Erreur execute');
    }

}

//header('Location: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);


?>
```

Comment: estas seguro que student_id es un string?

Comment: student_id es un campo de la tabla

Comment: si, pero en la tabla es un numerico o un string.. porque lo buscas como string...

Comment: Primero que todo, quiero dejar en claro que el uso combinado de comillas simples y dobles no es un error, por lo menos no para esta linea:

    `"select * from student where student_id = '$id_stud'"`

Prueba para todas las versiones de PHP: https://3v4l.org/0Z8aX

otro fuere el caso si se encontrase así:

    `'select * from student where student_id = "$id_stud"'`, Ahora podría ayudar que anexaras mas información como la estructura de tu tabla, ademas que puedes hacer uso de var_dump para evaluar el contenido de `$row`entre otras.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tu codigo asi como lo envias es propenso a SQL Inyeccion te recomiendo que te fijes como escapar variables con PHP y MYSQSL aqui: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Una version segura de tu codigo y adaptado de la documentacion oficial de PHP seria:

```
$query_string = sprintf("select * from student where student_id = '%s'",
            mysql_real_escape_string($id_stud));
$query =  mysql_query($query_string);
```

Luego por otro la libreria mysql esta oficialmente deprecada. Ademas que la query que te copio arriba en este caso funciona pero no funcionara en todos los casos en contra de inyeccion mysql.

Te dejo aca la informacion general sobre mysqli.
http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.overview.php

Te recomiendo consideres migrar de mysql a mysqli que trae otras ventajas no solo lo de la inyeccion sql.

Te dejo un ejemplo de como quedaria tu conexion y tu select con mysqli y prepared statement con bindeo y escape de variable, usando la interfaz de objetos de mysqli tambien existe una funciona igual que mysql.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "usuario", "password", "database");

/* check connection */
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Fallo Conexion: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("select * from student where student_id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $id_stud);

$stmt->execute();

$stmt->bind_results($resultado);

$stmt->fetch();

$stmt->close();
```

Comment: Es de valorar que propongas una método de escape alas variables, sin embargo tu juicio sobre el entrecomillado inicial es erroneo: `echo "select * from student where student_id = '$id_stud'";` es completamente valido

Comment: Es buena respuesta pero yo le **agregaría el comentario** de que es **sumamente importante** *migrar* de `mysql` a **`mysqli`**, en especial por que **`mysqli`** permite hacer **consultas preparadas**, donde se protege de muchas vulnerabilidades que poseía el ya en desuso `mysql`.

Comment: Agustin, muy cierto lo que decis, la edito y lo agrego. Con un par de referencias a mysqli. De hecho en nuevas versiones de PHP ya el viejo mysql empieza a mostrar mensajes de deprecated.

Comment: me sigue sin funcionar... debería después de ese código sacar el valor con $name = $row['firstname']; ??

Comment: lo siguiente parece estar bien, proba con php my admin ejecutar la query:
select * from student where student_id = 1; y pasale en el numero el mismo id que estas recibiendo de tu form para segurarte que los datos estan okey y tenes datos.

Despues ayudaria si nos podes decir que error te da.

Y tambien me gustaria ver un var_dump($query) y de var_dump($row) a ver que tienen adentro @Vieira

Comment: Añadiría una cosa: `mysql_real_escape_string` funcionará correctamente con ese ejemplo, pero no con otros, dejando el último método expuesto en la respuesta vulnerable a inyección SQL. Por ejemplo: `mysql_real_escape_string` no escapa los caracteres `%` o `_` lo que puede llevar a problemas si se usa `like`, `grant` o `revoke`; o si no se usan comillas (como parece que OP hace) y el atacante pone como valor `1 OR 1=1`, lo cual lleva a graves problemas si se está haciendo un `update`. Es mejor usar sentencias preparadas con MySQLi/PDO que `mysql_real_escape_string` (o mysql_* directamente)

Comment: me sale esto --> bool(false) NULL INSERT INTO events(title, id_teach, is_stud, start, end, color) values (' ', '9', '242', '2017-07-20 00:00:00', '2017-07-20 01:00:00', '#0071c5')

Comment: Finalmente me funcionó con $query_string... increiblemente no me funcionaba antes pero lo acabo de volver a probar y voalá.... Muchas gracias a todos

Comment: **Nunca, jamás** uses concatenación para construir una consulta: abres la puerta para ataques de inyección SQL. Referencia obligatoria: https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: Seguramente estabas mandando mal en algun momento el ID porque ahí sale vacío. Voy a hacer todas las ediciones sugeridas más tarde así queda bien la respuesta.

Answer (score 3):

Primero que todo, quiero dejar en claro que el uso combinado de comillas simples y dobles no es un error, por lo menos no para esta linea:

```
"select * from student where student_id = '$id_stud'"
```

Prueba para todas las versiones de PHP: https://3v4l.org/0Z8aX

otro fuere el caso si se encontrase así:

```
'select * from student where student_id = "$id_stud"'
```

---

Ahora asumamos que tu estructura es algo así:

```
CREATE TABLE `student` (
  `student_id` int NOT NULL,
  `firstname` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(40) default NULL
);
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE `events` (
  `title` mediumint NOT NULL,
  `id_teach` int NOT NULL,
  `id_stud` int NOT NULL,
  `start` datetime,
  `end` datetime,
  `color` varchar(10) default NULL
);
```

Teniendo en cuenta las sentencias `SELECT` e `INSERT` que muestras en la pregunta, entonces tu problema se resumen a un pequeño fallo de tipeo, puesto que tienes algo así:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO events(title, id_teach, is_stud, start, end, color) values ('$nombre', '$id_teach', '$id_stud', '$start', '$end', '$color')";
```

Opto por esta conjetura en base a que tienes un argumento `$id_stud` sin embargo en la consulta llamas al campo `is_stud` y dado que el campo no existe, no se permite que hagas la inserción.

Quiero enfatizar en que no estoy en contra de las sugerencias de los compañeros en escapar las variables y usar otra API como `mysqli`, puesto que demás estoy desacuerdo con ello. Sin embargo solo **intento recrear el verdadero error de tu consulta** y desmitificar el problema a causa del entrecomillado.

Comment: Gracias Parcero, editada mi respuesta asi tampoco presta a confusion deje solo las sugerencias sobre la inyeccion sql y el mysqli.

Answer (score 2):

No uso PHP, trabajo más con JavaScript, pero me parece que la SELECT está mal construida, passas el parámetro encerrado entre comillas. Por lo tanto la SELECT está buscando que `student_id = '$id_stud'` y no está buscando el valor de `$id_stud`.

Creo que la Select tendria que ser así:

```
"select * from student where student_id = '".$id_stud."'"
```

Comment: No me funciona con y sin comillas...

Comment: Si puedes acceder a la base de datos, mira un id, y prueba la consulta de forma directa.

Verifica que la variable no sea nula en el momento de hacer la consulta.

Comment: El id me pone "Nulo" NO... y veo que todos los campos se guardan menos este... cosa rara... el tema es que el POST de id_stud lo guarda bien

Comment: Tienes dos veces: $id_stud = $_POST['id_stud']; en el código no debería darte problemas, pero podría ser!